# Maximum call stack exceeded for ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In an aspx when I try to show rows less than 4000 gridview is loading but if it is more then it is throwing this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

But it is not showing in any exception in my cs file.

Comment: Could you check Chrome Browser's Console, and see which method triggers the error?

Answer (score 0):

actually this not an unhanded exception so you cannot catch it simply by a try/catch, you must control you gridview controller to not overcome the highest limit provided by this control